# Overleaf .png dont show

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

When I Compile, the pic doesn't load to the PDF. I added the package

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, png}
```

and try this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pic/pic/2.png}
\caption{Project 1 Grafic}
\label{grafic}
\end{figure}
```

IDK why this doesn't work.

This is what I see on my PDF when compiling

[image]

The Pic is named "2.png" and stored in "pic" folder

Comment: Is there a folder named pic inside your mentioned folder pic, as it seems as you call the folder twice?

Comment: Just a hint : you can avoid typing the extension and latex will find it on its own.

Comment: unrelated but `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, png}` would be better written as `\usepackage{graphicx}` (everything else is the default, and using that syntax makes it harder to switch to other engines such as luatex)

Comment: @Lukas u right. I changed it now, but still doesnt work.

Comment: LOL, I fixed the Problem: I changed the compiler setting. The Compile-mode has to be "normal" instead of "fast"